# Individual block diagonalisations take more time than single diagonalization of block matrix

Tags: code-review, scripting

Sample Problem of a large block matrix:

I want to find the lowest eigenvalue of a blockdiagonal matrix `h[x]`  for a range of values of `x`

- To save the time, I do so by finding the lowest eigenvalue of each block individually and then lowest out of them but

Individual block diagonalizations take more time than single diagonalization of block matrix `h[x]` for a range of values of `x`.

```
b0 = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {16, 16}]; c0 = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {64, 64}]; d0 = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {128, 128}]; e0 = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {32, 32}];
b = b0 + Transpose[b0];
c = c0 + Transpose[c0];
d = d0 + Transpose[d0];
e = e0 + Transpose[e0];
h[x_] := x*SparseArray[Band[{1, 1}] -> {b, c, d, e}];
AbsoluteTiming[ParallelTable[-Eigenvalues[-h[x], 1, Method -> {"Arnoldi", "Criteria" -> "RealPart"}][[1]], {x, 0.1,5., 0.1}];][[1]]
blocks[x_] :=ConnectedComponents@AdjacencyGraph@Unitize@h[x]
eigbloc0[x_, bl_] := -Eigenvalues[-h[x][[#, #]], 1, Method -> {"Arnoldi", "Criteria" -> "RealPart"}][[1]] & /@ {blocks[x][[bl]]}
eigbloc1[x_] := Table[eigbloc0[x, bl], {bl, 1, 4, 1}]
AbsoluteTiming[ParallelTable[Min[Flatten[{eigbloc1[x]}]], {x, 0.1, 5., 0.1}];][[1]]
```

**Output:**

`7.98266`

`11.7006`

I was expecting lower time for individual block diagonalization, Could anyone suggest me the resolution ?

Comment: One issue is that you rebuild the full matrix each time you want to compute only a block, because `eigbloc0` calls `h`. Ideally, you know the blocks already independently of the construction of the matrix -- because you know _how_ to construct the matrix.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Yes, For a single computation, say  `h[x=1.0]`, Individual digonalization procedure is faster. Could you please tell me how to avoid the repetitive computations in above program  ?

Comment: Try this: `ClearAll[blocks];
blocks = 
  Range[#1 + 1, #2] & @@@ 
   Partition[Accumulate[{0, 16, 64, 128, 32}], 2, 1];
eig[x_] := Module[{A},
   A = -h[x];
   Min@Table[
     -Eigenvalues[A[[block, block]], 1, 
       Method -> {"Arnoldi", "Criteria" -> "RealPart"}],
     {block, blocks}
     ]
   ];`

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher, You are wonderful, Worked!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First issue is that you compute the matrix each time you try to compute within a block.
Second issue is that you *recompute* all the blocks themselves.

So this was just not a fair comparison. Have a look at this example. Even *without* parallelization, computing the eigenvalues of the dense diagonal blocks is two orders of magnitude faster:

```
n = 100;
diagonal = # + #\[Transpose] &[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {#, #}]] & /@ 
   RandomInteger[{120, 240}, {n}];
A0 = SparseArray[Band[{1, 1}] -> diagonal];


val1 = -Max[Eigenvalues[-A0, 1, 
       Method -> {"Arnoldi", "Criteria" -> "RealPart"}]]; // 
  AbsoluteTiming // First
val2 = -Max[Eigenvalues[-#, 1, 
         Method -> {"Arnoldi", "Criteria" -> "RealPart"}] & /@ 
       diagonal]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
val1 == val2
```

> 5.35384
>
> 0.063925
>
> True

I guess the main speedup here comes from the fact that replace a the sparse matrix vector multiplication kernel by many small, highly efficient dense matrix-vector multiplication kernels. (Sparse matrix multiplication typically has quite a "random" memory access pattern, so the compute kernels do not optimize for contiguous memory access (because they cannot).)